# I can't understand how uplevel works

Tags: tcl

Why do I get an error ?

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
proc add {a} {
  uplevel 1 $a
   puts $a
}
set n 0
add $n
```

I can't understand how uplevel works

Comment: When asking these sorts of questions, it can help a lot to put the error message in your question.

Answer (score 2):

`uplevel` executes some code in a different "stack frame" -- each time you invoke a procedure (and some other ways), Tcl adds an execution frame to the call stack.

Here's an example:

```
proc foo {} {
    set fooVar 42
    bar {expr {$fooVar + 21}}
}

proc bar {code} {
    puts "in bar, code is: [list $code]"
    puts "in bar, the fooVar variable [expr {[info exists fooVar] ? "does" : "does not"}] exist"
    uplevel 1 $code
}
```

Running the `foo` procedure:

```
% foo
in bar, code is: {expr {$fooVar + 21}}
in bar, the fooVar variable does not exist
63
```

This is demonstrating that, because we're executing the code in one frame up in the call stack, the code fragment **does** have access to a local variable in that frame.

If we try to run `bar` with the same code block from the glocal scope, we'll
see an error:

```
% bar {expr {$fooVar + 21}}
in bar, code is: {expr {$fooVar + 21}}
in bar, the fooVar variable does not exist
can't read "fooVar": no such variable
```

But if we set the variable in the global scope, it works as expected:

```
% set fooVar -1
-1
% bar {expr {$fooVar + 21}}
in bar, code is: {expr {$fooVar + 21}}
in bar, the fooVar variable does not exist
20
```

---

Together with [upvar](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm), the [uplevel](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/uplevel.htm) command allows you to implement your own control structures -- Tcl is really an incredibly flexible language. An example:

```
proc foreachWithIndex {variableNames aList code} {
    lassign $variableNames idxVar elemVar
    upvar 1 $idxVar idx
    upvar 1 $elemVar elem

    set idx 0
    foreach elem $aList {
        uplevel 1 $code
        incr idx
    }
}

foreachWithIndex {i e} {a b c d} {puts "$i -> $e"}
```

```
0 -> a
1 -> b
2 -> c
3 -> d
```

Answer (score 0):

If we run your code, we get the error message: `invalid command name "0"`.

Let's investigate by printing the stack trace:

```
% puts $errorInfo
invalid command name "0"
    while executing
"0"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $a"
    (procedure "add" line 2)
    invoked from within
"add $n"
```

That looks curious, but it is fine because the value of `$a` is `0` because the argument to `add` is the value of `$n` which is `0`. The arguments to `uplevel` (after an optional first pseudo-numeric argument, which you *are* supplying; good!) are a script (with multiple arguments being concatenated). The string `0` *can* be a script, if you happen to have a command in scope whose name is the single digit `0`, but that's pretty unusual.

Once it's got the script to run, `uplevel 1` runs the script in the context of the caller of the current procedure. (Technically, it steps up `1` stack frame and runs it there. Tcl stack frames actually form a tree, though there's usually just one branch on the tree at a time; `uplevel` forms another branch.)

The two common forms of `uplevel` are `uplevel 1` (for “run in the caller”) and `uplevel #0` (for “run in the global scope”). There are others, but they're uncommon. Don't use `uplevel 0`; it's exactly like `eval` and confusion reigns if you get obscure like that.

It's good practice to usually keep your `uplevel` script forms to one of:

1. An argument passed in by the caller. (This is your script's case.)
2. A constant script.
3. A single command call *generated by calling `list`*. You can use `{*}expansion` when generating the list; this is a good way to handle a list of values or a command prefix.

All of these have been found to be generally non-confusing and fairly easy to use correctly (without weird hazards). Other options tend to be tricky.

---

I'm guessing your code should have *actually* been written like this:

```
proc add {varName} {
    upvar 1 $varName v
    set v [expr {$v + 1}]
    # Or maybe: incr v
    puts $v
}
set n 0
add n
```

The `upvar` command uses the same level resolution rules as `uplevel`, but instead *aliases* a named variable in that scope to the other local name in the current scope. A call to `upvar #0 foo foo` is functionally equivalent to the apparently simpler `global foo`.